# AWSのRDSのMySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aws

AmazonウェブサービスのRDSに最近デビューしました。そこでMySQLを使用してみましたがどうにも外部キーを指定してあるテーブルに制約違反で挿入できません。バージョンも変えてみましたが変わりません。どなたかご存じありませんか？

ローカルでは問題なく動いているのと、それとは別に単純な外部制約を定義した挿入‌​はRDSでも動くことを確認いますのでなにかRDS特有のものがあるのではと思い質問させていただきました。

Comment: 恐らくそれはRDSの問題ではないです。クエリやテーブルの制約を見直してみて下さい。 それともっと具体的な例を書いた方が良い回答が得られるはずです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りクエリやテーブルが怪しいと思っているのですがローカルでは問題なく動いているのと、それとは別に単純な外部制約を定義した挿入はRDSでも動くことを確認いますのでなにかRDS特有のものがあるのではと思い質問させていただきました。

Comment: どういう構成のテーブルにどういうデータを挿入しようとしたのか、その手順、どういうエラーメッセージが出たのか、などの具体的な情報を明確にしないと回答が付かないと思います。

Comment: 順当に言って、外部キー制約に引っかかったなら、外部キーに指定されたカラム値を持つレコードが無いのだと思いますが。 そうでない、しかしエラーになるというならやはり、具体的なメッセージと実行したクエリ、データの抜粋が無いと有効な答えは出てこないでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

ローカルは Windows か Mac OSX でしょうか。
もしそうであれば、RDS では 大文字小文字を区別するので SQLクエリを 実際のテーブル名と同じように変更してください。

例えば `CREATE TABLE` で `MyTable` としてるのに SQLで `mytable` とした場合にエラーになります。

別の回避方法としては RDS のパラメータグループから [`lower_case_table_names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) の値を `1` に変更してください。ただし、[RDSのドキュメント](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.ParameterNotes.lower-case-table-names)によるとDB インスタンスの作り直しが必要なようです。